# How to wire a button to increase or decrease score using onclick?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

If I click the buttons then the game score will increase or decrease based on which button I click.

Comment: post your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create two buttons in the xml : --

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/decrease"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:onClick="decreaseInteger"
         android:text="-"
         android:textColor="@color/white" />

 <Button android:id="@+id/increase"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:onClick="increaseInteger"
         android:text="+"
         android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

now in your activity:--

```
Integer minteger = 1
    public void increaseInteger(View view) {
        if (minteger < (your upper limit)) {
            minteger = minteger + 1;
            display(minteger);
        }
    }

    public void decreaseInteger(View view) {
        if (minteger > 1) {
            minteger = minteger - 1;
            display(minteger);
        }
    }
```

and display can be a method to update your view:--

```
private void display(int number) {
       // do something with your number
    }
```